# How to detect and record the time when the button is pressed in C#?

Tags: c#, button, time, recorder

For instance, if there is a push button, when the user press the button, the system should detect and record the time in dd-mm-yy. However, if the user press the button many time in 2 second, the system should only record the first time when the user press the button.

Comment: please show us your attempt

Comment: Hi Jazb, I haven't try the coding because I don't have any idea about this question.

Comment: Sometimes it's OK to ask a question without code when the poster _["is trying to do something specific"](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/286760/585968)_.  However we might need to know a few things first.  What type of app is this? WinForms? WPF? Web?

Comment: The type of the app is WPF

Answer (score 0):

Assumption: you want to collect clicks but no more often than every 2 seconds. This simple form will do it.

Code:

```
namespace RecordClicks {
        public partial class Form1 : Form {
    
            private DateTime _recordedClick = DateTime.MinValue;
    
            public Form1() {
                InitializeComponent();
            }
    
            private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    
                DateTime currentClickTime = DateTime.Now;
    
                if (currentClickTime.Subtract(_recordedClick).TotalMilliseconds > 2000 ) {
                    _recordedClick = currentClickTime;
                    lblClick.Text = currentClickTime.ToString();
                    // TODO: add code to record this click
    
                }
    
            }
        }
    }
```

Designer:

```
namespace RecordClicks {
    partial class Form1 {
        /// <summary>
        ///  Required designer variable.
        /// </summary>
        private System.ComponentModel.IContainer components = null;

        /// <summary>
        ///  Clean up any resources being used.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="disposing">true if managed resources should be disposed; otherwise, false.</param>
        protected override void Dispose(bool disposing) {
            if (disposing && (components != null)) {
                components.Dispose();
            }
            base.Dispose(disposing);
        }

        #region Windows Form Designer generated code

        /// <summary>
        ///  Required method for Designer support - do not modify
        ///  the contents of this method with the code editor.
        /// </summary>
        private void InitializeComponent() {
            this.button1 = new System.Windows.Forms.Button();
            this.lblClick = new System.Windows.Forms.Label();
            this.SuspendLayout();
            // 
            // button1
            // 
            this.button1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(121, 241);
            this.button1.Name = "button1";
            this.button1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(132, 53);
            this.button1.TabIndex = 0;
            this.button1.Text = "Clicker";
            this.button1.UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
            this.button1.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.button1_Click);
            // 
            // lblClick
            // 
            this.lblClick.AutoSize = true;
            this.lblClick.Font = new System.Drawing.Font("Segoe UI", 24F, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Regular, System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Point);
            this.lblClick.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(121, 127);
            this.lblClick.Name = "lblClick";
            this.lblClick.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(90, 45);
            this.lblClick.TabIndex = 1;
            this.lblClick.Text = "Time";
            // 
            // Form1
            // 
            this.AutoScaleDimensions = new System.Drawing.SizeF(7F, 15F);
            this.AutoScaleMode = System.Windows.Forms.AutoScaleMode.Font;
            this.ClientSize = new System.Drawing.Size(800, 450);
            this.Controls.Add(this.lblClick);
            this.Controls.Add(this.button1);
            this.Name = "Form1";
            this.Text = "Clicker Test";
            this.ResumeLayout(false);
            this.PerformLayout();

        }

        #endregion

        private Button button1;
        private Label lblClick;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the provided code. However, the type of app is not form. Is that any method to record the time for press the button in WPF?

Comment: Same concept, the code is just a demonstration